# How to quickly view an xarray DataArray in a table-like format?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-xarray

I am an intermediate Python user with most of my experience in Pandas, trying to switch over to xarray. I am working in Jupyter Lab. When I run a line of code of just the name of a  `xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray` object, I get something like this:

[image: A screenshot of an xarray DataArray]

I would like to be able to print and see the beginning of a DataArray in a table-like format, as I would be able to with a Pandas DataFrame:

[image: A screenshot of a Pandas DataFrame]

But I can't seem to figure out a quick and easy way to do this. Looking at a DataArray as it normally prints out is a little inconvenient. It's hard to match up a coordinate with a data point.

I have tried `da`, `da.head`, and `print(da)`. None of them gave me the table format I wanted. I am not sure what else to try beyond just converting it to a DataFrame and printing it out as I used to.

Comment: What's wrong with something like `print(da.to_pandas().head())`?

Comment: or `print(da.head().to_pandas())` - this would be quicker

Comment: generally, xarray tries to balance clarity/ease of use with performance and flexibility, and these tensions are often at odds. xarray is designed around N-dimensional arrays, so displaying as a table just doesn't work without reformatting the data into one, and this is not a optimal from a performance standpoint for many workflows. xarray uses numpy (or whatever the backend is, e.g. dask) to display the array preview, so the array format will be the same as the numpy layout.